# plug-in estimator of variance

Tags: statistics

The answer to this question should be easy and a comment will be enough, but I am just struggling with it...

Let $F$ be a cumulative distribution function and $\mu$ the mean corresponding to a random variable which follows $F$. Let $\sigma^2=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2dF(x)$ be the variance and $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})^2$ be the plug-in estimator of $\sigma^2$, where $X_i\sim F$ are iid.

Why is it true that $\mathbb E[(\bar X -\mu)^2]=\frac{1}{n}\sigma^2$?

I was thinking I need the distribution of $\bar X$ to figure out what the answer is but this seems too complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true because

$$\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n-\mu]^2=\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}_n]=\mathbb{V}\Bigg[\frac{1}{n}\Sigma_i X_i\Bigg]=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{V}[\Sigma_i X_i]=\frac{1}{n^2} n\sigma^2=\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$$